# Black screen and blinking cursor on boot on second drive with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ssd, external-hdd, macbook-pro

Kind of new to Ubuntu here. I have a 250 gb HDD and 525 gb SSD, both with installed Ubuntu 16.04. After installing the OS on any of the 2 from USB flash drive, the one with I just installed works and boots perfect. Problem is when I connect the one I set up before, it does not boot and gives me a black screen with blinking cursor. Then I reinstall Ubuntu on the latter and it works, but when I try to boot the other one same things happens, and so on.

Eventually I will install Windows7 on the HDD but before I have to make sure that I have a running version of Ubuntu on at least one drive in case things go wrong (which is guaranteed not to happen with the current symptom).

Any idea of what is the issue? Thanks